# How can I get the jobid number of multiple job submitted on slurm by a python script?

Tags: slurm

I have a script called Script1.py that launched a bunch of calculation. I want to have then finished before running Script2.py.

I tried to gather all the JobID of those calculations in CalcScript1 to set it as depedency of Script2.py but it is not working. How can I build this pipeline?

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=2880
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --output=2880.logfile
#SBATCH --time=480:00:00

cd ${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}

#Loading modules
module load intel/18.0.5.274
module load libraries/intelmpi/2018.4.274

#Launching calculation

python Script1.py 
CalcScript1=$(squeue -u $USER | grep 'Name_File_Generated_Script1*' | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs)
sbatch  --dependency=afterany:$CalcScript1 python Script2.py
```

I submitted the file and recover this as error. On this example Script1.py is only generating 1 calculation with the jobID 139001.

`Submitted batch job 139001 File number 1 , xyzfilenum0001.xyz sbatch: error: This does not look like a batch script.  The first sbatch: error: line must start with #! followed by the path to an interpreter. sbatch: error: For instance: #!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from the fact that you submit an executable (`python`) rather than submission script. To do that, you need to use the `--wrap` parameter:

```
sbatch  --dependency=afterany:$CalcScript1 --wrap "python Script2.py"
```

What's more, the `afterany` option accepts a *colon-separated list* so your `CalcScript1=$(...)` ligne should insert `:` characters between the job ids.

Also note that your regular expression `grep 'Name_File_Generated_Script1*'` matches `Name_File_Generated_Script1`, `Name_File_Generated_Script11`, Name_File_Generated_Script111`, ... not sure this is what you want. You might be missing a dot` .`before the`*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was one part of the problem! 
The other one was that the squeue command print only a limited number of characters to overpass this issue, I used :

squeue --format="%.18i %.9P %.30j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R" -u $USER